# Google Sheets formula for substitute text

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Hi I'am using Google sheet and I want a function to do this look at the exemple ,
Exemple :have a cell **[A1]** contain "**HI MY NAME IS SOUFIANE**" ..... I want to Substitute  "MY"  by "you" and Substitute "SOUFIANE" by "Alex" on cell **[B1]**.

*can you help me please*

I do this formula but it does not work

=SUBSTITUTE(AND(A1, "My", "you"),(B1, "soufiane","Alex"))

Comment: =SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"MY","YOU"),"SOUFIANE","ALEX")

Answer (score 2):

`=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"(.*)MY(.*)SOUFIANE","$1you$2Alex")`